# why push_back and emplace_back when combined together, have different behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

In the following code:

```
struct aa
{
   int a;
   aa( int x):a(x){ cout<<"const is called"<<endl;}
   ~aa(){cout <<"dest is called"<<endl;}
   aa( aa&& obj)
   {
       a = obj.a;
       cout<<"move const is called"<<endl;
   }
};
int main ()
{
  vector<aa> v1;
  v1.push_back(aa(9)); 
  v1.emplace_back(9);
}
```

1. when only `push_back` is used, result are expected ( Move constructor  , constructor and destructor are called .)

Results:

```
const is called
move const is called
dest is called
dest is called
```

2. When  only `emplace_back` is used , result are expected ( No Move constructor is called , only constructor and destructor are called .)

Results:

```
const is called
dest is called
```

3. **but when I combined  `push_back` with `emplace_back`, why move constructor is called for `emplace_back` while it was not called when used separately) ?**

Results:

```
const is called
move const is called
dest is called
const is called
move const is called
dest is called
dest is called
dest is called
```

Comment: I reopened the question becaus I think the point here is not the difference between `push_back` and `emplace_back`, but why use them together leads to unexpected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you use both `push_back` and `emplace_back`, you're adding two elements to `v1`. At the 2nd time reallocation happened, new inner buffer is created and existing elements are copied/moved to new inner buffer.

You can use `reserve` in advance to prevent reallocation.

```
vector<aa> v1;
v1.reserve(2);
v1.push_back(aa(9)); 
v1.emplace_back(9);
```

Comment: Thanks @ songyuanyao